# Passing data between tables in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have several tabs in the same worksheet. I need to pass a selected single row of customer data which could be in any position in the table, between any one of six tables, one each within the six tabs.

One column "**Process Phase**" has the conditional formatting to trigger the move to the specified table, in this case from "**Prospects**" to "**Order Title**".

I am working on the first two tabs, "**Prospects**" and "**Order Title**".
I successfully pass the data from "**Prospects**" to "**Order Title**", but I am not able to control where the data is copied and have not figured out a way to auto expand the table size and also keep the formatting and other cell functionality.

I will ultimately need to pass data between any one of the six tables into the FIRST row of the table, auto size the table and move a selected row of data between tables from any position in any of the other tables to the FIRST row of any other table selected, without writing over the existing data.

Here is the Trigger:

' In Sheet1 (Prospects)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Z = 1 To Target.Count
        If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then
            Call MoveBasedOnValue
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Here is the macro:

' In Module 2, Move "Prospects" to "Order Title"

```vb
Sub MoveBasedOnValue()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    
    A = Worksheets("Prospects").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Order Title").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    If B = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Order Title").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Prospects").Range("H1:H" & A)
     
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Order Title" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Order Title").Range("A" & B) '("A" & B + 1)
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Order Title" Then
                C = C - 1
            End If
            B = B + 1
        End If
         
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: Editor2]

[image: Worksheet]

[image: Editor]

I am able to pass data, but not position it or re-size the tables.

Comment: Things will be easier if you use listobjects for your tables